# Back button issue in Angular and Capacitor

Tags: angular, capacitor

I am using Capacitor plugin with Angular 8 and when I click on back button in Android then it redirects to login page and also it's not come in backButton listener.

```
App.addListener('backButton', (res) => {
console.log('back res', res);
if (this.activeModal.hasOpenModals()) {
  

    this.activeModal.dismissAll();

} else if (this.router.url === '/home/dashboard' || this.router.url === '/home/dashboard/control') {
  
    this.showConfirm();

} else if (this.router.url === '/landing/forgot-password') {

    this.router.navigateByUrl('/landing/login');

} else if (this.router.url === '/landing/login') {

    this.showConfirm();

} else {

    this.location.back();

}
});
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Are you using Ionic?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a few weeks ago.
So I have done the following:

```js
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(1, () => {
                //check if logged or not or do something
        });
    });
}

// or 
this.platform.backButton.observers.pop();
```